# Difference in bundleID btw npx expo run:ios and development build + npx expo start --dev-client?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-build

I'm developing an iOS app and implementing a RevenueCat integration. To simplify, RevenueCat relies on the bundleID of the app to connect to Apple to fetch the right subscriptions created on the account.

I originally had one version of my app using the bundleID `com.x.x` - this is the version I published to Testflight and was running locally. It all worked - RevenueCat could use that bundleID to get the subscriptions I set up in App Store Connect.

Because I wanted to have both the latest Testflight version and a development version that I could iterate on on my phone simultaneously, I then followed [these instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variants/) to create a variant - I gave the variant the bundleID `com.x.x.dev`, and registered that in App Store Connect. I created parallel subscriptions for that new 'app' in the App Store as well.

The trouble now is that RevenueCat can't seem to use the new bundleID to detect any offerings. I've double checked the configuration of everything and all the values seem to be correct.

On the screen I’m screenshotting below, it shows the bundleID (read from `{Constants.expoConfig.ios.bundleIdentifier}`) and, if it can fetch offerings info, shows that.

I noticed today that when I build the app with `npx expo run:ios`, which ends up running on my computer on iOS Simulator, the code actually *works*:
[image]

But when I try to run the code via a development build, ie running `eas build --profile development --platform ios` to download it onto my phone then running `npx expo start --dev-client`, it still does not work:
[image]

Based on how RevenueCat works, this suggests an intriguing possibility: that in the first screenshot, it's reading the `com.x.x.dev` bundleID from my `app.config.js`, but is still using the old `com.x.x` bundleID behind the scenes.

I'm throwing this question to the Expo tag in the hopes my hypothesis is right - is there something different about how these two build methods work such that the former might be using a different (the original) bundleID in the background? Is there any way for me to check what is the 'actual' bundleID being used?

Comment: Confirming that the underlying bundleIDs are indeed different. I used `DeviceInfo.getBundleId()` from the library `react-native-device-info` to confirm that on the iOS simulator build, even though it sees the different bundleID from the app.config.js, it's still using the original bundleID. The question now is - why? Why didn't the iOS simulator build use the value from app.config.js?

Comment: Got the same issue. Don't feel alone.